# Tensorflow install from Source (Win7): bazel, python -> No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, windows-7-x64, bazel

## Goal

Use Python-trained (keras) model in c/c++.
See section work-around for c-work-around.

Compile Tensorflow from source (rev 1.0 or 1.2.1)
following the instructions from

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

(tensorflow already is installed via pip in python3, but I need to use it from c++, so installing from source seems mandatory)

## System

- win7(64)
- bazel 0.5.2,
- python(env) 3.5.2 (64),
- pip(env) 9.0.1,
- msys64/msys2_shell.cmd (GNU bash, 4.4.12  (64-pc-msys))
- gcc 6.3.0
- java SE "1.8.0_131",
- CUDA 8.0.60 (not used).

## Error

(full logs are below in extra sections)

in msys2-shell, setting environment vars, activate python virt-env, doing bazel clean, ./configure,

```
bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get this error:

```
  ERROR: D:/user/sourcen/external/tensorflow-master-201707051514/
            tensorflow-master-rev-1-2-1/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1415:1: 

  Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed: 

  bash.exe failed: error executing command

  cd C:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_user/chogfwdz/execroot/org_tensorflow

  C:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe 
                              -c source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; 
                                        tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py 
                              --generate tensorflow/tools/git/gen/spec.json 
                                         tensorflow/tools/git/gen/head 
                                         tensorflow/tools/git/gen/branch_ref 
                                            "bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc": 
                                              com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.
  BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 3.

  Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Sorry, I am absolutely lost here, this message tells me nothing.
Here some snippets from the files mentioned above, maybe somebody has a glue and gives me a hint for enlightment....

---

//tensorflow/core/BUILD:1415:1
     tf_version_info_genrule()

```
 cc_library(
     name = "version_lib",
     srcs = ["util/version_info.cc"],
     hdrs = ["public/version.h"],
     copts = tf_copts(),
 )
```

---

bazel/.../genrule-setup.sh

```
 set -e
 set -u
 set -o pipefail
```

---

//tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py

```
  """... creates symlinks from the internal git repository directory so
  that the build system can see changes in the version state. ..."""

  def parse_branch_ref(filename)...
  def configure(src_base_path, debug=False)...
  def get_git_version(git_base_path)...
  def write_version_info(filename, git_version)...
  def generate(arglist)...
  def raw_generate(output_file)...
```

---

I suppose, that the wrong python version is used (not the virtualenv I activated) - there are several other python versions (2.7-32, 2.7-64, 3.5-32, 3.5-64) installed (which are needed otherwise).

## Questions

What can I do to check, if bazel is using the right python (virtualenv)?

If bazel is using the wrong one, how can I change this?

If bazel is using the right version, how can I get more details about what is going wrong (and fix it)?

### Meta-Questions

What further information are needed (environment variables)?

What can I do to improve the question to enable people to give advices?
(please give comments, what is missing, wrong, unclear, too much)

### Next steps

I searched for "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'"

- tried to do the procedure below with a local admin account -> blocked by the company firewall
- tried to set PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, no effect.

  export PYTHONHOME=/D/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35

  export PYTHONPATH=/D/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35:
                    /D/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/lib/site-packages:
                    /d/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/libs
- try to set up another virtualenv (as admin)
- try to install tensorflow via cmake

### Procedure

This is what I did after starting msys2:

In TF 1.0, I did a work-around for the first problem I faced (download failure of numeric_min_js).
After some IRC talk & lots of tries - finally I commented out one line in
 /tensorflow-rev1-0/tensorflow/tensorboard/bower/BUILD (see below).

So now ./configure script (TF 1.0)  runs without errors (warnings about http_proxy can be ignored, as I 've been told on IRC and on some URLs I googled). Below I added full logs of the full build-attempt.

My Python virtual-env is in

```
d:/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/python.exe,
```

As library-path I used:

```
D:/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/lib/site-packages.
```

## TF 1.0 attempt

### patching BUILD (TF1.0)

```
.../tensorflow-rev1-0/tensorflow/tensorboard/bower/BUILD

 filegroup(
     name = "bower",
     srcs = [
    ...
         # "@numericjs_numeric_min_js//file", # by rg20170710
    ...




 user@CRPC0815 MSYS ~     
$ cd /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0/
```

### step 0: set env, activate python-env, cd

start msys2-shell:

```
 $ c:/tools/msys64/msys2_shell.cmd
```

set the environment variables

```
  user@CRPC0815 MSYS ~
 $ source d:/user/00-Projekte/VrVis/env-cuda-python64-3--1.sh
```

activate virtual-env

```
 $ cd /d/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/
 $ source activate python64-35
```

goto sources

```
 $ cd /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0

  (python64-35)
  user@CRPC0815 MSYS /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0
 $
```

### step 1: bazel clean

```
 (python64-35)
 user@CRPC0815 MSYS /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0
$ bazel clean
 WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
 ....................
 INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
```

### step 2: ./configure

```
 (python64-35)
 user@CRPC0815 MSYS /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0
$ ./configure

 Please specify the location of python.
     [Default is /D/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/python]:

 Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation [Default is -march=native]:

 Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N]
  No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow

 Found possible Python library paths:
   D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\lib\site-packages
   D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35
 Please input the desired Python library path to use.
   Default is [D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\lib\site-packages]

 Using python library path: D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\lib\site-packages

 Junction created for util\python\python_include <<===>> D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\include

 Junction created for util\python\python_lib <<===>> D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\lib\site-packages

 Junction created for third_party\py\numpy\numpy_include <<===>> D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\
                                                                    python64-35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include

 Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]
 No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow

 Configuration finished

 WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
 INFO: All external dependencies fetched successfully.
```

### step 3: bazel build & error

```
 $ bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

  WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.

  INFO: Found 1 target...

  ERROR: D:/user/sourcen/external/tensorflow-rev1-0/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1227:1:
   Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed:
    bash.exe failed:
     error executing command

      cd C:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_user/hnxszhzu/execroot/org_tensorflow

      SET PATH=C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;C:\tools\msys64\bin;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Library\usr\bin;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Library\bin;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Scripts;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;
               D:\user\bin\BLAS;
               D:\bin\TDM-GCC-64\bin;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\bp2qlotc.p22\NativeBinaries\x86;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;
               C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;
               C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;
               C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;
               C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\cuDNN\bin;
               C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\cuDNN\lib;
               C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;
               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
               C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
               C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015;
               C:\WINDOWS;
               C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
               C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
               C:\WINDOWS\system32;
               D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
               D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin;
               D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin\awk;
               D:\bin\CMake\bin;
               D:\bin\Git\bin;
               [...]
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\DLLs;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Lib;
               D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\libs;
               D:\bin\Slik-Subversion-1-9-2\bin;
               D:\bin\SubversionColabnet\bin;
               D:\bin\TDM-GCC-64\bin;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\local\bin;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;
               C:\tools\msys64\opt\bin;
               C:\Windows\System32;
               C:\Windows;
               C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
               C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\site_perl;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;
               C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\core_perl

    C:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe -c source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh;
                                        tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py
                                     --generate tensorflow/tools/git/gen/spec.json
                                                tensorflow/tools/git/gen/head
                                                tensorflow/tools/git/gen/branch_ref
                                                 "bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc":
                                                  com.google.devtools.build.lib.

    shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 3.

  Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

  Current thread 0x0000628c (most recent call first):
  Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
  INFO: Elapsed time: 5,500s, Critical Path: 0,41s
```

## TF 1.2.1 build attempt

### step 0: set env, activate python-env, cd

(the same as in TF 1.0)

```
 $ source d:/user/00-Projekte/VrVis/env-cuda-python64-3--1.sh
 $ cd /d/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/
 $ source activate python64-35
 $ cd /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-master-201707051514/tensorflow-master-rev-1-2-1/
```

### step 1: bazel clean

```
 $ bazel clean

  WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
  INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes
```

### step 2: ./configure

```
 $ ./configure

  WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.

  You have bazel 0.5.2- installed.

  Please specify the location of python.
    [Default is /D/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/python]:

  Found possible Python library paths:
    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35
    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\lib\site-packages
  Please input the desired Python library path to use.
    Default is [D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35]
  D:/bin/Python64-3-Anaconda/envs/python64-35/lib/site-packages

  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N]
  No MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow

  Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified
    [Default is -march=native]:

  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N]
  No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow

  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]
  No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow

  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]
  No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow

  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]
  MPI support will not be enabled for TensorFlow

  Configuration finished
```

### step 3: bazel build & error

```
  (python64-35)
  user@CRPC0815 MSYS /d/user/Sourcen/external/tensorflow-master-201707051514/tensorflow-master-rev-1-2-1
 $ bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

  WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.

  INFO: Found 1 target...

  ERROR: D:/user/sourcen/external/tensorflow-master-201707051514/tensorflow-master-rev-1-2-1/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1415:1:
         Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed:
          bash.exe failed:
           error executing command

           cd C:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_user/chogfwdz/execroot/org_tensorflow

           SET PATH=C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;
                    C:\tools\msys64\bin;
                    C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin;
                    D:\user\bin\BLAS;
                    D:\bin\TDM-GCC-64\bin;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\bp2qlotc.p22\NativeBinaries\x86;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\;
                    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;
                    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;
                    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;
                    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\cuDNN\bin;
                    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\cuDNN\lib;
                    C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;
                    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
                    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
                    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
                    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015;
                    C:\WINDOWS;
                    C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
                    C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
                    C:\WINDOWS\system32;
                    D:\BaslerPylon5\Runtime\Win32\;
                    D:\BaslerPylon5\Runtime\x64\;
                    D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
                    D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin;
                    D:\user\bin\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin\awk;
                    D:\bin\CMake\bin;
                    D:\bin\Git\bin;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Library\bin;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Scripts;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\DLLs;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\Lib;
                    D:\bin\Python64-3-Anaconda\envs\python64-35\libs;
                    D:\bin\Slik-Subversion-1-9-2\bin;
                    D:\bin\SubversionColabnet\bin;
                    D:\bin\TDM-GCC-64\bin;
                    D:\bin\gnuplot\bin;
                    D:\user\bin;
    .
    C:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe -c source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh;
                                        tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py
                                     --generate tensorflow/tools/git/gen/spec.json
                                                tensorflow/tools/git/gen/head tensorflow/tools/git/gen/branch_ref
                                                 "bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc":
                                                  com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.

    BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 3.

  Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

  Current thread 0x000036e8 (most recent call first):
  Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build

  INFO: Elapsed time: 5,413s, Critical Path: 0,52s
```

### Work-Around

Meanwhile I found a work-around for deploying Tensorflow (Keras) Models (win7/win10) without need of bazel/cmake/sources....:

- use the C-API c_api.h from [win/cpu](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.5.0.zip), [c-api example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305647/segmentation-fault-when-using-tf-sessionrun-to-run-tensorflow-graph-in-c-not-c/44588221#44588221)
- create lib from dll via vs2015 command prompt:

  dumpbin /exports xxx.dll > xxx.def

  pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib
- extract gpu lib from Python pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib
- copy pyd lib _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd to dll-path
- maybe use gpu-options (python -> c):
- python code

  gpu_options = tensorflow.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)

  config = tensorflow.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)

  serialized = config.SerializeToString()

  [int(i) for i in serialized]
- c-code for gpu-options:

  TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();

  // tensorflow.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True) ...

  uint8_t configProtoGPU[] = { 50, 2, 32, 1};

  size_t configProtoGPUlen = sizeof(configProtoGPU) / sizeof(uint8_t);

  TF_SetConfig(sess_opts, configProtoGPU, configProtoGPUlen, status);